# Как обратится к динамически созданному элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Из базы данных подгружаются комментарии. У комментариев есть несколько уровней, т.е. ответы на них. Проблема в том, что 1-й и 2-й уровни комментариев выводятся, а вот дальше уже нет. Куда аппендить я определяю по айди самого комментария и по уровню самого комментария/ответа. Я понимаю, что js видит элементы на странице на момент инициализации кода. Но как мне аппендить "ответы" в таком случае, если элементы создаются динамически? Подскажите как работать с динамическими элементами, а то я уже не знаю что делать... Использую такую конструкцию:

```js
var commLevel = o[i].level,
  commId = o[i].id_comments;

switch (commLevel) {
  case '0':
    item.addClass('first_lvl')

    $('.commentlist').append(item);

    break;
  case '1':
    item.addClass('reply second_lvl')

    $('.first_lvl.id_' + commId).append(item);

    break;
  case '2':
    item.addClass('reply third_lvl')

    $('.second_lvl.id_' + commId).append(item);

    break;
  case '3':
    item.addClass('reply fourth_lvl')

    $('.third_lvl.id_' + commId).append(item);

    break;
  case '4':
    item.addClass('reply fifth_lvl')

    $('.fourth_lvl.id_' + commId).append(item);

    break;
  default:
    console.log('Error');
```

Comment: Что мешает сохранить ссылки на добавленные элементы?

Comment: Т.е. запихнуть их в переменные? Если да, то пробовал, результат тот же. Просто не срабатывает append(). Но тогда почему второй уровень вставляется, а дальше всё...

Comment: 1. Скорее сохранить в массив. 2. Не верю.

Comment: Так и есть. В .commentlist заносится .first_lvl, в .first_lvl заносится .reply.second_lvl и в него .reply.third_lvl уже нет

Comment: Заноси то что ты добавляешь в append.